# How to force DataGrid group order in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have code like this:

```
StatusItems = new ObservableCollection<StatusItem> { };
StatusItemsGrouped = new ListCollectionView(StatusItems);
StatusItemsGrouped.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("GenericStatus"));
StatusItemsGrouped.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("GenericStatus", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Basically I am grouping data on a `DataGrid` based on info called `GenericStatus`. Everything is fine except the sorting. What I want to achieve now is to sort the groups in Descending order (as my code does), but the problem with the above code is that as soon as the user clicks on some column, the sorting is ruined.

I want to retain the group sorting, *but still allow user sorting*. The user sort will be basically a secondary sort I guess, i.e. I want this: `ORDER BY GenericStatus DESC, UsersColumnOfChoise ASC/DESC`.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself and my solution was to intercept the Sorting event and let the ICollectionView do the sorting in the ViewModel instead of relying on the DataGrid to handle it.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StatusItemsGrouped}" Sorting="OnSorting_"/>
```

XAML.CS:

```
private void OnSorting_(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as ViewModel;
    e.Handled = true;                                 // prevent DataGrid from sorting
    viewModel.SortItemSource(e.Column);               // perform sorting
    e.Column.SortDirection = viewModel.SortDirection; // set sort direction icon on column header
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public ListCollectionView StatusItemsGrouped { get; set; }
    public ListSortDirection SortDirection { get; set; }
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }

    public void SortItemSource(string columnName)
    {
        if (String.Compare(SortColumn, columnName, true) == 0)
            SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        else
            SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
        SortColumn = columnName;
        using(StatusItemsGrouped.DeferRefresh()) {
            StatusItemsGrouped.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
            StatusItemsGrouped.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            StatusItemsGrouped.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(SortColumn, SortDirection));
            StatusItemsGrouped.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("GenericStatus"));
        }
        StatusItemsGrouped.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: An excellent answer.  I modified it heavily for my use, but it lead me to the solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to setup each column click as a "Command" - then watch the command to be executed and add it as a sorted column, in addition to your GenericStatus.

Create a CommandStub:

```
private bool sortAscending;
private CommandStub _sortList;
public ICommand sortList {
    get {
        if (_sortList == null) {
           _sortList = new CommandStub();
           _sortList.OnExecuting += new CommandStub.ExecutingEventHandler(_sortList_OnExecuting);
        }

        return _sortList;
   }
}

void _sortList_OnExecuting(object parameter) {

    var sortColumn = (string)parameter;
    StatusItems.SortDescriptions.Clear();

    if (sortAscending) {
        // Always sort first by GenericStatus
        StatusItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("GenericStatus", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        // Sort by the column clicked
        StatusItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        this.sortAscending = false;
    } else {
        // Always sort first by GenericStatus
        StatusItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("GenericStatus", ListSortDirection.Descending));

        StatusItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortColumn, ListSortDirection.Descending));
        this.sortAscending = true;
    }
}
```

Each column header has a Command associated to it which is called when the user clicks to sort:

```
var h = new GridViewColumnHeader();
h.Command = sortList;
h.CommandParameter = "deviceName";
```