# WinUI3: How to sort datagrid groups?

Tags: datagrid, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3

I'm using the [Windows Community Toolkit Datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.controls.datagrid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0).

I am binding the the datagrid's ItemSource to a grouped CollectionViewSource.

```xaml
<ctWinUI:DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyCollectioViewSourceView, Mode=OneWay}"
```

By default groups are sorted alphabetically:

[image: alphabetically sorted groups]

How can I implement custom sorting?

(Note I know how to sort datagrid rows, this is specifically for sorting datagrid groups.)

I have seen [similar questions for the WPF datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409874/sorting-datagrid-groups), but the WinUI datagrid is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just order the `Source` of the grouped `MyCollectioViewSourceView`, e.g.:

```
CollectionViewSource cvs= new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.IsSourceGrouped = true;
cvs.Source = groupedItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, in hindsight that's super simple and makes sense. Thanks!